# Convert From EST to GMT Time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, timezone

How to write query to Convert From EST to GMT Time considering day light savings?

Ex: EasternTime is `2010-02-13 11:30:55.293`

If this falls in day light savings, it should be `2010-02-13 15:30:55.293`
otherwise it should be `2010-02-13 16:30:55.293`

Please help

Comment: What sql data type is datetime value? Do you have datetime offset stored?

Comment: yes it is datetime. offset is not stored

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server?? Version 2008 introduced a lot of additional functions (and datatypes) to deal with timezones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current conditions, you can't do a reverse conversion to UTC *cleanly*, since there is already ambiguous time entries present (then time is switching back in time).

Other than that, you will need [SQL CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function for such conversion, since SQL server have no access to time zone data AFAIK. You should use [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class for your task.